# Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined in Angular 8 custom web component

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, web-component

I am building a custom web component using angular 8. I have noticed that Angular 8 doesn't have `--single-build true`, so i used the following code

```
(async function build() {
   const files = [
     "./dist/bundle/runtime-es2015.js",
     "./dist/bundle/polyfills-es2015.js",
     "./dist/bundle/styles-es2015.js",
     "./dist/bundle/scripts.js",
     "./dist/bundle/vendor-es2015.js",
     "./dist/bundle/main-es2015.js"
   ];

  await fs.ensureDir("elements");
  await concat(files, "elements/bundle.js");
})();
```

I have excluded the `...-es5.js` files. The following code works when i remove all scripts tags in the `index.html` file and use `bundle.js` but when i import the custom element in another project i get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` from the following line :

```
*/           var jsonpArray = window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || [];
/******/     var oldJsonpFunction = jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);
/******/     jsonpArray.push = webpackJsonpCallback;
```

`window["webpackJsonp"]` returns a function instead of an array causing `jsonpArray.push.bind(jsonpArray);` to error. Came across **ngx-build-plus**, `--single-bundle` works but excludes the global styling only imports component scss, tried including `--bundle-styles false` and `--keep-styles` in the `ng build`, it didn't work.

How can i solve the following error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined` when i concat all files ? Take note i am sing angular webpack not custom webpack. 2nd how can i make `ngx-build-plus` render global scss ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following link [Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9766) helped me a lot. To add `jsonpFunction: "o3iv79tz90732goag"` in angular 8 had to `npm i @angular-builders/custom-webpack` and create a webpack config file see below: see [documentation](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack) for @angular-builders/custom-webpack

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    jsonpFunction: 'wpJsonpBundle'
  }
};
```

Then add the custom webpack config file to angular.json

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
           ....
```

After ng build, i then concatenate the files using the function in the question and can use the custom element in other angular projects.