# Event emitter in custom web elements in Angular 8

Tags: angular, web-component, custom-element

created a custom web element in angular 8 using [angular elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements) and [web components](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/webcomponentsjs). `@input()` and  `new EventEmitter()` become disabled so to input a value to the component i use `ElementRef`:

```js
 this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('name');
```

in my app.module file i added the following code :

```js
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const el = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {
      injector: this.injector
    });

    customElements.define('person', el);
  }
}
```

After building the project I then [bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59196209/cannot-read-property-bind-of-undefined-in-angular-8-custom-web-component) all the js file in the dist to 1 file. All that is good, but i cant emit an event from the component to the parent. i import the bundled js file in the script tag and and call `<person name="name"><person>` in the html. Tried to add an event listener but the event needs to be available across the project more like a global event, i tried the following :

```js
// component (angular 8)
const event = new CustomEvent('notification', {
   detail: {
       message: 'good person',
       type: 'info'
     }
});
const person= document.getElementById('person');
person.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```js
// pure html project
const person= document.getElementById('person')
person.addEventListener("notification", () => //some code );
```

but when the project execute the custom event detail is always null its like the component and the project are not communicating. How can i add a global event emitter that will cover both projects ?

Comment: What you meant by @Input() and EventEmitter() disabled?

Comment: @KavindaJayakody The Idea is to convert a component to a custom element, but angular input and output don't seem to work. have to use js custom event to send data outside the element

Comment: It usually works. I have created a whole UI kit using angular elements (Custom Elements) and all i used is @Input() and EventEmitters

Comment: Ah.... Remembered one thing. Did you named your input() something like userName (camelCase)? If so, you have to turn them to lowercase or when you are using them - You have to make the attribute name to lowercase (like <custom-element username='user'>

Comment: @KavindaJayakody Thank you will change my naming convention and try again, will advise.

Comment: Good luck pal. Make your to mention if it's works, so that can be posted as the correct answer to help others too

Comment: @KavindaJayakody tried to change the name and didn't work, i think its the way i setup the project  because i have changed my index.html file to ``<body>
<person id="person" name="name"></person>
</body>`` then i use `@webcomponents/custom-elements and zone.js` in polyfills. inside the component i use   `this.elementRef.nativeElement`

Comment: Can you post your full code? Not the full app, i meant the needed things for us to clarify the issue. Use plunkr or jsfiddle or anything